C++ Arrays - must have constant value error
I was learning Merge Sort Algorithm and when I copied the exact code I got an error that "expression must have a constant value" even though it ran without issue for the instructor. I am using both Visual Studio Code and Microsoft Visual Studio. For VS Code it acknowledges the error but runs but not in Microsoft VS. I tried using const int before array declaration and it still gave an error. I know I can use dynamic allocation and deallocation, but why does it work for him but not me.
void merge(int array[], int leftIndex, int midIndex, int rightIndex) {
    int leftArraySize = midIndex - leftIndex + 1;
    int rightArraySize = rightIndex - midIndex;

    int leftArray[leftArraySize]; // error 1 underlines leftArraySize
    int rightArray[rightArraySize]; // error 2 underlines rightArraySize

    // rest of the code... 
}


Some compilers offer variable length arrays as extensions, some don't.  Sounds like MSVC doesn't offer it, at least with your build flags.

MSVC never had VLA support, in C++ mode at least. Modern versions have C support, but I never tried it there

even though it ran without issue for the instructor -- Get a new instructor.  A C++ teacher should know that variable length arrays are not part of C++.  If the teacher was not aware of this, then who knows what other ill-advised things they will teach you when learning C++.
